# Limit Admin Logins to 3 persons over LAN in Visual Studio App

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, admin, lan, login-control

I set up an Admin login by creating a user name and password area which gives the admin access to forms that a typical user  will not see .

lets say 4 persons are using this application , i want to make it that only 3 of the 4 persons can login as Admin.

How do I do this ?

this is how i created my login function .

in the settings area of my application i created two names `DBUsername` and `DBPassword` and set their scope to `User`

`PasswordField` and `NameField` are the text boxes
this is a photo of the login area and the code behind it . The function works perfectly.

do not pay attention to the `User Login` button

[image]

```
Public Class login
Private Property username As String = ""
Private Property password As String = ""

Dim Setting As New My.MySettings

Private Sub AdminLoginButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AdminLoginButton.Click

    If NameField.Text = "" And PasswordField.Text = "" Then
        Label3.Text = "PLEASE ENTER A USERNAME AND PASSWORD"
    End If
    If NameField.Text = "" And PasswordField.Text.Length > 0 Then
        Label3.Text = "PLEASE ENTER A NAME"
    End If
    If PasswordField.Text = "" And NameField.Text.Length > 0 Then
        Label3.Text = "PLEASE ENTER A PASSWORD"
    End If

    'generage first password 
    If Setting.DBpassword = "" Then
        'save password here
        password = PasswordField.Text
        Setting.DBpassword = password
        Setting.Save()
    Else
    End If

    'generate first username
    If Setting.DBUsername = "" Then
        username = NameField.Text
        Setting.DBUsername = username
        Setting.Save()
    Else
    End If
    'check if correct name and password are entered 
    If PasswordField.Text = Setting.DBpassword And NameField.Text = Setting.DBUsername Then

        Label3.Text = ("WELCOME " & NameField.Text)
        Dim itm As Control
        Me.Close()
        For Each itm In MLGMain.Controls
            itm.Enabled = True
        Next

    End If

    If NameField.Text.Length >= 1 And NameField.Text <> Setting.DBUsername And PasswordField.Text.Length >= 1 And NameField.Text <> Setting.DBpassword Then
        Label3.Text = "INCORRECT USERNAME AND PASSWORD COMBINATION"
        NameField.Clear()
        PasswordField.Clear()
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need some sort of mechanism to count the admin logins. You could set up a SQL server table on the LAN that would be accessed by all the computers. This table would maintain information about who is logged into the system. You would need to make sure that they are properly logged out at the end of the session.

Comment: sounds difficult :) i like difficult , good learning experience .

i am thinking of creating a new `name` in the settings are called `usersin` and set the scope to `user`
I add 1 to a int everytime an admin logs in and save the value . if it reaches 3 then make it so  no more can log in ??  maybe ?